# Solve the problem of react icons showing object inside js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When adding icons inside the js condition, the icon appears as an object only, and the icon does not appear

```
{!signUp ? `${(<FcGoogle />)}` + "Signin With Google": `${(<FcGoogle />)} SignUp With Google`}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjLyO.png)

Comment: btw, assuming this would work, when using `` you dont need to concat a string anymore but could do sth. like this: `{!signUp ? \`${(<FcGoogle />)} Signin With Google: ${(<FcGoogle />)} SignUp With Google\`}`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals for more info on this

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put components inside a string since they are functions that do not return strings. You could either remove the `` around  or (IMO) better:

```
<button
  className="btn"
  type="submit"
  disabled={disabled}
  onClick={handleClick}
>
  <FcGoogle />
  {!signUp ? "Signin" : "Signup"} With Google
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the icon we render doesn't change depending on the value `signUp`; a cleaner approach to solve this challenge would be use a ternary inside the string and conditionally render the text like below:

```js
export function SignInOrSignUp({ signUp }) {
  return (
    <>
      <FcGoogle /> {`${signUp ? 'Signin' : 'Signup'} With Google`}
    </>
  )
}
```

This has the added benefit of [keeping our code DRY](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/what-is-dry-development) also.